# Insert Drawable shape to View

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-drawable

I would like to send each time different Drawable shape to view and then add it to my activity.
The problem is I can't find a way to add the drawable shape into the canvas when I'm overriding the `onDraw` method.

The design supposed to be reusable, I can draw rect first and then draw circle...

**I want to find a way to send the view different shape. Is it possible?**

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      // Draw the ball
      ballBounds.set(ballX-ballRadius, ballY-ballRadius, ballX+ballRadius, ballY+ballRadius);
      paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
   // canvas.drawOval(ballBounds, paint);
      canvas.drawRect(ballBounds, paint);
}
```

Comment: You should use scale property of canvas.

[follow this link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183372/how-to-properly-scale-a-game-on-android

Answer (score 0):

Although, your question needs more explanation on what you need, but with what I could understand is you want rect, or circle on desire, here it is,

Add, global variable `int ShapeStructure = 0;`

```
    @Override
       protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
       {
          // Draw the ball
          ballBounds.set(ballX-ballRadius, ballY-ballRadius, ballX+ballRadius, ballY+ballRadius);
          paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
if(ShapeStructure == 0){
        canvas.drawOval(ballBounds, paint);
}else{
          canvas.drawRect(ballBounds, paint);
}
       }
```

Now that, you have a variable at your disposal, you can control what you want to paint.

Hope, this helps, let me know if you want something else.